# BA protocol soundness explanation

Tags: algorithm-design, soundness

I was reading the following paper [BA-made it trivial](https://people.csail.mit.edu/silvio/Selected%20Scientific%20Papers/Distributed%20Computation/BYZANTYNE%20AGREEMENT%20MADE%20TRIVIAL.pdf)
and when talking about BA agreement protocol in page 3, I didn't understand what it meant by soundness here.

> A
> protocol P is an arbitrary-value (respectively, binary) (n, t)-Byzantine agreement (BA) protocol
> with soundness σ ∈ (0, 1],

so when is the soundness 1 or 0? or is the soundness true if it follows some rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soundness is the probability that the protocol works as intended and can be any real number greater than 0 and less than or equal to 1. Different designs will have different probabilities of working as intended. Generally, higher soundness is better. In particular, if we have a protocol with soundness 1, it will always work as intended. However, it may not always be practical to achieve soundness this high. Nevertheless, provided that we have a non-zero chance of success, we can repeat the protocol until we can believe that there should be a sufficiently high probability of having witnessed a correctly behaving instance.